# Running Flutter Doctor without any results

Tags: macos, installation, dart, console-application, flutter

After cloning successfully flutter, I try to execute 'flutter doctor' but I don't get any results, even a wait for more than 60 minutes.

I have tried several versions, also the **beta branch**, also searched in the repo issues and stackoverflow without success. The most similar issue is this one  [[12295]](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12295) (but I'm connecting from Spain) also tried from several public IP's.

**Macbook info:**

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.4
BuildVersion:   17E199

Here is a step by step.

**Cloning the repo:**

```
Macbook:~ ben$ git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Cloning into 'flutter'...
remote: Counting objects: 119704, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
remote: Total 119704 (delta 29), reused 29 (delta 20), pack-reused 119619
Receiving objects: 100% (119704/119704), 36.36 MiB | 5.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (89707/89707), done.
```

### Flutter Doctor for first time

It starts downloading and stops after 'Downloading Gradle Wrapper...'  I think it starts 'flutter doctor' but there's no results.

```
Macbook:~ ben$ flutter doctor -v
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 09d05a38912a3c1a906e95099cac9a7e14fae85f...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 43.9M  100 43.9M    0     0  16.7M      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 16.7M
Building flutter tool...
Downloading Material fonts...                                0,6s
Downloading package sky_engine...                            0,2s
Downloading common tools...                                  0,6s
Downloading darwin-x64 tools...                              1,8s
Downloading android-arm-profile/darwin-x64 tools...          0,6s
Downloading android-arm-release/darwin-x64 tools...          0,6s
Downloading android-arm64-profile/darwin-x64 tools...        0,6s
Downloading android-arm64-release/darwin-x64 tools...        0,8s
Downloading android-x86 tools...                             1,8s
Downloading android-x64 tools...                             2,0s
Downloading android-arm tools...                             1,5s
Downloading android-arm-profile tools...                     1,1s
Downloading android-arm-release tools...                     0,9s
Downloading android-arm64 tools...                           1,5s
Downloading android-arm64-profile tools...                   1,4s
Downloading android-arm64-release tools...                   1,1s
Downloading ios tools...                                     2,9s
Downloading ios-profile tools...                             4,7s
Downloading ios-release tools...                             2,5s
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                0,4s
^C
```

**Flutter Doctor (no results):**

```
Executing 'flutter doctor -v' without results

Macbook:~ ben$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
^C
Macbook:~ ben$ flutter doctor -v
```

**Flutter version:**

```
Macbook:~ ben$ flutter --version
Flutter 0.3.3-pre.1 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 315993e (5 hours ago) • 2018-04-20 14:49:33 +0200
Engine • revision 09d05a3891
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: try to switch the channel to beta `flutter channel beta`

Comment: I have already tried the beta branch as I said, but thanks @OleksandrKravchuk